# How to Configure WCF for CRM 2016 IFD

Tags: wcf, wsdl, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a CRM instance that has been updated from CRM 2011 to CRM 2016 IFD.  I have an old .net 3.5 website that was working just fine with CRM 2011 using a WSDL added service reference.  Changes where required to the website to pass in credentials, now that it is IFD (ADFS 3.0).  Those changes have been made.  But since it is IFD, I need to change the WCF bindings to point use https and WS-Trust.  When I walk through the SDK examples, it says I should be able to point to the Wsdl, to generate the WCF config.  The Config is completely empty.  I have been able to successfully do this with a 2011 CRM instance that is IFD (ADFS 2.0).

So how do I configure the WCF ABCs?  Does CRM 2016 no longer allow this?  Do I have a potential ADFS configuration issue (it is also currently requiring users to enter their user name and password when hitting CRM locally, even when on authenticated Domain Machines, so this is entirely possible.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therefore your looking to change your code to work with IFD in CRM 2016.

The topic of authentication is covered here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334502.aspx

You also likely want to look at oAuth as well.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531010.aspx

Comment: I'd prefer not to change the code at all.  It's "going away" in the near future, and is currently working with CRM 2011 using WSDL service references... I'm wondering if I have the ADFS incorrectly configured...